# Wordpress genesis theme - changing the logo from text to graphic

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the vanilla Geneis theme with no child, but I cannot find where the logo should reside. I can change the favicon no worries, but I see no logo file present and I see no advice on how to add to the "parent" theme - I'm not using a child.

Is there a way to add a logo. I have changed the settings in wordpress for a logo rather than text (in the header settings). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I haven't done this on the default Genesis theme, I have replaced the main headline text with just a logo.  I posted how I did it on the [Genesis Forum](http://www.studiopress.com/support/showthread.php?t=101814), but here it is.

If you want to keep the rest of the genesis_do_header hook in place, you can just replace the default genesis_do_header using the child theme's functions.php.

Open up functions.php and add the following:

```
// Replace header hook to include logo 
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' ); 
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_new_header' ); 
function genesis_do_new_header() { 
    echo '<div id="title-area"><img src="your/logo/image.jpg" alt="Site Logo" />'; 
    do_action( 'genesis_site_title' ); 
    do_action( 'genesis_site_description' ); 
    echo '</div><!-- end #title-area -->'; 
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'header-right' ) || has_action( 'genesis_header_right' ) ) { 
        echo '<div class="widget-area">'; 
        do_action( 'genesis_header_right' ); 
        dynamic_sidebar( 'header-right' ); 
        echo '</div><!-- end .widget-area -->'; 
    } 
}
```

You can then style the image with your CSS in the following fashion:

```
#title-area img {
    float:left;
}
```

You should now see your logo floated to the left of your site title.  You may have to tweak some things, as the themes aren't identical, but let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried this, but not got it working as yet. I've added the functionality but it seems not to have worked.

Comment: Strangely there were no functions in the function. Only require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lib/init.php' );

Comment: Here is what I get in the HTML: `<div id="header"><div class="wrap"><div id="title-area"><img src="http://www.XX.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/5.jpg" alt="Site Logo" /><p id="title"><a href="http://www.XX.co.uk/" title="SXX.co.uk">XX.co.uk</a></p><h1 id="description">putting you in the network</h1></div><!-- end #title-area --><div class="widget-area"><div id="text-10" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap">   <div class="textwidget"></div>
  </div></div>`

Answer (score 5):

Not to resurrect an old post or anything but I found a solution that works better than the one proposed above:

If you want to remove Title and Description then add following code in functions.php. This is useful when you decide to use site logo instead of text for site title.

```
/** Remove Title & Description **/
remove_action( 'genesis_site_title', 'genesis_seo_site_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_site_description', 'genesis_seo_site_description' );
/** Remove default site title and add custom site title **/
remove_action( 'genesis_site_title', 'genesis_seo_site_title' );
function custom_site_title() { 
     echo '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'" title="My Website"><img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url(254).'" alt="My Website"/></a>';
}
add_action( 'genesis_site_title', 'custom_site_title' );
```